# Is there a published development/deployment schedule for Firefox?

Tags: firefox

There's [a bug of sorts](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=828839) that will get fixed in Firefox 20 (they're currently in 18, just released), and I was curious to know whether there's any resource or anything that'd let me estimate when FF20 would be released.

I'm assuming there's obviously no precise dates, but just something that'd let me know whether that might take 2 weeks or 6 months, since that affects what I have to do in my code to work around that code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox 20 (for developers) will be released round about April 2013.
Nightly builds are currently available for download but of course, this is not stable.

More info on changes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_20_for_developers

Note: Changelog is still in draft

Answer (score 1):

There's a schedule at https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar and I'd stop the answer there, but stackoverflow demands more characters.  ;)